# Calculate n day growth rate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
'country_code', 'count_date', 'case_count'
CAN           ,  2020-09-01 ,  1700000
CAN           ,  2020-08-31 ,  1650000
...           ,  ....       ,  ....
SGP           ,  ....       ,  ....
...           ,  ....       ,  ....
USA           ,  ....       ,  ....
...           ,  ....       ,  ....
```

It is sorted as:

```
df = df.sort_values(['country_code','count_date'], ascending=[True,False])
```

Suppose f(x) is case_count on date x, then I need to calculate:

```
(f(x) - f(x-7))/(f(x-8) - f(x-15)
```

for every country_code

I could calculate difference between consecutive dates as below:

```
df['dailynew_cases'] = df.groupby('country_code')['case_count'].diff(-1)
```

But how to calculate 7 days (or n day) growth rate and save it another column in the same DF?

EDIT #1:
pct_change function doesnt match with the desired output. Below are the values for USA on 2020-08-29

```
case_count = [5867633.0, 5573695.0, 5529672.0, 5248806.0] 
count_date = [datetime.date(2020, 8, 28), datetime.date(2020, 8, 21), datetime.date(2020, 8, 20), datetime.date(2020, 8, 14)]
```

Desired output is `(5867633.0-5573695.0)/(5529672.0-5248806.0) = 1.0465`
But pct_change gives 0.0518

Answer (score 2):

To get growth rate, you can use [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html)

```
df['growth'] =  df.groupby('country_code')['case_count'].pct_change(periods=7)
```

Comment: For that I have to sort the dates in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this using `shift`

```
df['growth_rate'] = df.groupby('country_code').case_count.transform(lambda x: (x.shift(-1) - x.shift(-n)) / (x.shift(-n-1) - x.shift(-n-n))*100)
```